# Why is competitive inhibition reversible?

Tags: biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics

My Biochemistry book mentions that 'competitive inhibition' is a reversible form of inhibition.
 But given that the inhibitor is blocking the active site and prevents an enzyme-substrate complex to be formed, how can it be reversible?

Comment: Not all competitive inhibition is permanently irreversible. Only substrates which bind covalently are irreversible. Something like Narcan(Naloxone) is a competitive antagonist, but it is not permanent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A **[competitive inhibitor](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/netorial/modules/biomolecules/modules/enzymes/enzyme5.htm)** typically [competes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compete) for the [active site](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/energy-and-enzymes/introduction-to-enzymes/a/enzymes-and-the-active-site) with the [substrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substrate_(chemistry)). In this [textbook case](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/textbook%20case/example), [binding](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Protein_function/Binding_Sites) of a [competitive inhibitor](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/netorial/modules/biomolecules/modules/enzymes/enzyme5.htm) is [reversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics)), because it [binds](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structural_Biochemistry/Protein_function/Binding_Sites) to the [active site](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/energy-and-enzymes/introduction-to-enzymes/a/enzymes-and-the-active-site) of the [enzyme](http://www.novozymes.com/en/about-us/our-business/what-are-enzymes/pages/default.aspx), but is also [released](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22084072), making way for the [substrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substrate_(chemistry)) to [bind](http://biowiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Biochemistry/Binding/Reversible_Binding%3A_1._Equations_and_Curves). The [affinity](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/netorial/modules/biomolecules/modules/enzymes/enzyme4.htm) of the [substrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substrate_(chemistry)), as well as its [concentration](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Biological_Chemistry/Catalysts/Enzymatic_Kinetics/Enzyme_Inhibition) determine the amount of [inhibition](http://chemistry.elmhurst.edu/vchembook/573inhibit.html) [(Berg *et al*., 2002)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/).

An [irreversible inhibitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_inhibitor) may [covalently bind](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Theoretical_Chemistry/Chemical_Bonding/General_Principles_of_Chemical_Bonding/Covalent_Bonds) to the [active site](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/energy-and-enzymes/introduction-to-enzymes/a/enzymes-and-the-active-site), [permanently](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/permanent) [disabling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disable) the [enzyme](http://www.novozymes.com/en/about-us/our-business/what-are-enzymes/pages/default.aspx) [(McDonald *et al*., 2012)](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/netorial/modules/biomolecules/modules/enzymes/enzyme5.htm).

<sub>**References**

**-** [McDonald *et al*., *Enzymes: Irreversible Inhibition*. In: eLS. John Wiley & Sons Ltd, Chichester (2012)](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/netorial/modules/biomolecules/modules/enzymes/enzyme5.htm)

**-** [Berg *et al*., *Biochemistry*. 5<sup>th</sup> ed. New York: W H Freeman; (2002)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/)</sub>

Comment: In light of [this meta post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/when-are-citations-needed-in-an-answer), this might be the single greatest answer of all time. I had a good laugh.

Comment: @canadianer thanks :-) It was a bit of an over-reactive response to someone claiming the answer was undersourced (a whole string of comments has been deleted since). Admittedly, it was indeed undersourced, but to me its contents are common knowledge and I didn't even bother to source it. Well, after it had been scrutinized even in a meta post, others began to interfere, mainly long-term residents here who knew I was probably among the last deserving to be blamed for not sourcing his answer :) Eventually it lead to the above result....

Comment: The high number of upvotes is totally not representative of its quality, it's just that people appreciate the principle of sourcing answers to that extreme point where it becomes just plain silly :)

Comment: @xusr thanks for your input. It sounds like you could write an excellent answer. In the meantime, I have adapted the wording of my answer above to reflect your thoughts. My approach was to give a schoolbook answer to a schoolbook question. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: It's water under the bridge, but if I were writing a schoolbook answer I would have included a diagram and an equation. School books are the most highly reviewed and edited form of literature. The publishers stand to lose a lot if they get things wrong in a very lucrative corner of the market.